# Namespace alias inside a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a following structure of namespaces

```
namespace a::b::c
{
   class xyz{

   };

   using x=xyz
}
```

1. If I want to refer to x in an outside file, How should I address it?  is it like `a::b::c::x` or just `x`?
2. To be able to refer to it as `x` outside my code, how can I change the above code? Can I write `using x=a::b::xyz` inside the namespace a::b::c?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `x` is introduced in the namespace `a::b::c`

```
namespace a::b::c
{
   class xyz{

   };

   using x=xyz
}
```

So in the global namespace to refer to the name `x` you have to write

```
a::b::c::x
```

You could introduce the alias in the global namespace like

```
using x = a::b::c::xyz;
```

Alternatively you could use a using declaration like

```
using a::b::c::x;
```

in this case you can use the unqualified name `x` in the scope where the using declaration is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you need to understand that `namespace` means a new name space in order to distinguish between possibly similar names.

When you use: `namespace a::b::c` you add to all of the names inside it the prefix `a::b::c`, therefore, you must call it using `a::b::c::x` as you mentioned (and you can easily check it on your own!). Only ***inside*** of that namespace, you can use it as `x`.

You can use it in other places by including it into the namespace, by putting `using a::b::c::x`, but I don't understand why you want to do such a thing.

If you want to use it everywhere, just put the `using x = a::b::c::x` ***outside*** of the namespace.

But, namespaces are created with a good purpose, please avoid removing the namespace prefix by doing any of these, it is just a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a namespace in the first place is for the purpose of avoiding variable-name collisions. When you use a `using` directive or create a global namespace alias, you're defeating the purpose of having used namespaces in the first place and re-establishing the danger of creating such a collision in order to avoid extra typing. Instead, use copy-paste editing or simply create a custom snippet in your IDE. (Or just type it out.)